# systemd restarts ntp every few hours. Why?

Tags: systemd

I have three raspberry pis running Bullseye. I don't know when it started (and obviously why), but ntpd is being restarted every 2 hours. All I can see in either the journalctl output or in daemon.log is

```
Dec  8 04:43:43 ntp1 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Service...
Dec  8 04:43:43 ntp1 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Service.
Dec  8 04:43:43 ntp1 systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Service...
```

ntpd doesn't seem to be doing anything wrong. How can I figure out why systemd is doing this and stop it?

ntpd in this case is configured as a stratum 1 server with a local PPS refclock, so that's why I'd rather it not restart for no reason.

Here's the ntp service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Time Service
Documentation=man:ntpd(8)
After=network.target
Conflicts=systemd-timesyncd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# Debian uses a shell wrapper to process /etc/default/ntp
# and select DHCP-provided NTP servers if available
ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As an experiment I stopped the ntp service and started ntpd manually with the same arguments and it's been running ever since. This doesn't solve the problem, but it proves that in the absence of interference from systemd, ntpd is stable.

Is systemd limiting the amount of CPU time a service consumes, per chance? If I look at another Raspberry Pi running NTP that is *not* doing the GPS thing, it is also being periodically restarted by systemd, but every *eleven* hours instead of every two. I wish there was a way to ask systemd **why** it was doing this.

Comment: Any "not related" crontabs every 2 hours?

Comment: No. None of the systems have other than the stock crontab file. And to be somewhat more specific, it's roughly every 2 hours. Timings on one system today are 1:08, 2:54, 4:43, 6:30, 8:22, 10:08, 11:54. Not very cron-like IMHO.

Comment: First thing I would do is stop it, then run it manually and see if it stops voluntarily within a couple of hours. Perhaps whatever is supplying the pps is restarting, then so does ntp. The logs so seem to be saying that it is systemd which is restarting it. So I would look at dependencies in the services files.

Comment: I've added the service file. I don't see any dependencies in it. systemd-timesyncd is not installed. The systemd wrapper checks for dhcp based configuration, but there is none.

Comment: I have done a sytemctl stop ntp and manually started ntpd with the same command line options. I'll edit this comment in a few hours with the results. My guess is that it will keep running normally.

Comment: Sure enough, I stopped the ntp service and started ntpd manually with the same arguments and it's been running ever since. This doesn't solve the problem, but it proves that in the absence of interference from systemd, ntpd is stable.

Comment: I wonder if this is network related. Just a thought that flaky WiFi maybe affects systemd's behaviour. Baybe not thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be dhcpcd's fault. There are hooks in /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks that are intended to rewrite ntp.conf to add or remove hosts specified in the DHCP lease. In my case, there are no such hosts, yet dhcpcd is bouncing ntp anyway. Neutering 66-ntp.conf (by commenting out the content of the if statement at the bottom of it) prevents this at the cost of eliminating support for DHCP based NTP configuration, but I'm fine with that in this case.

Comment: Perhaps it could be modified to bounce ntp only if the file content has changed?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a bug in the script.  Dhcp should not be bouncing ntp if it isn't making any changes.

Comment: I've opened an issue over at the dhcpcd GitHub repo. For me, I'm satisfied to just neuter the script until/unless it gets fixed upstream.